# Can not bind updated oData to sapui5 view

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am getting oData from backend.its data with timestamp and I need to get the difference from those timestamp.Which I did like bellow code.Now I want to add my that timestamp array to my view.Can I push those new array data to the view or how can I add update data to my sapui5 view.
Bellow are the codes.xml view:

GenericTile class="cm_productTile sapUiMediumMarginTop" header="Flow" visible="{=${dataResults>/flowSelected}==='true'}">


/flow}" class="sapUiSmallMarginTop">

<core:Fragment fragmentName="castor.fua.FUAsapui5FE.fragments.flowMainNode" type="XML"/>
<core:Fragment fragmentName="castor.fua.FUAsapui5FE.fragments.flowSubNode" type="XML"/>

var flowData = this.getView().getModel("elementsDataModel").oData.flow;
//for (var i = 0; i < flowData.length; i++) {

```
                        console.log(flowData);

                        var differences = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < flowData.length - 1; i++) {
                            var diff = new Date(flowData[i + 1].createdAt) - new Date(flowData[i].createdAt);
                            var diffMins = new Date(diff).getSeconds();
                            differences.push({diff:diffMins});
                        }
```

So differences array is the new data and I need to add those values in the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the backend, best way is to calculate the timestamp difference in the backend and expose it as a property of your oDataModel.
Alternatively (but I don't know if it fits your requirements) you can put your data coming from the oData model in a JSONModel, elaborate them and then bind this JSONModel with the new 'timestamp' column to the view.

Comment: Yes.I can save the data from in oData and modify them.After set the modified data in another model.Problem is can I bind two model to the view.As one model is already bound to the view which is  elementsDataModel from oData.Thank you.

Comment: You can have only one unnamed (main) model, which is  usually the oData model, but you can bind as many named models as you want to a view or a subpart of it  ;-)